# unable to connect any of the specified MySQL host c# application from windows pc trying to connect mysql server on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu

I have C# application installed all my LAN PC having windows 10 OS, and my central server has Ubuntu 16.04 installed on which mysql server is installed and my C# application communicate to the central server, it's working well some time, but some time it gives "unable to connect any of the specified MySQL host.

I have changed mysql configuration file as:
bind-address to "my server ip address" and also check it by "0.0.0.0",
make #skip-networking comment,
open 3306 port,
allowed 3306 port in firewall, 
increase max_connections,
grant user to access from % address,

And in my c# application i used standard way of connection string

It was working very well before when my server was on windows,
It is working very well without any error from my website

Answer (score 0):

Check connection string. Some times it's matter for Mysql (with spaces!):

```
Server=server_host_name; Port=port_number; Database=myDataBase; Uid=user_name; Pwd=passwoed;
```

Comment: I have checked it multiple time, it's ok. Sometime it work very well but sometimes it give the problem